# Making entire li / Action Link clickable

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, bootstrap-4

I have a hamburger menu and with a dropdown, I'd like the entire drop down to be clickable. Here's what I have now. Currently only the text is clickable.

cshtml

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-primary">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Foo</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsingNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="collapsingNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item a">
            @Html.ActionLink("Bar", "Index", "Bar", null)
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item a">
            @Html.ActionLink("Quax", "Index", "Quaxx", null)
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

css / bootstrap:

```
.navbar-collapse {


-ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar-toggler {
  padding: 0.25rem 0.75rem;
  font-size: 1.25rem;
  line-height: 1;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.nav-item{
  height: 50px;
  border-color: white;
  border-width: 2px;
  border-top: 1px dotted #d5d5d5;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #d5d5d5;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-item a{
  color: white;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: larger;
}
```

Basically, I would like the whole row / entire width for each menu item to be clickable

[image]

Comment: Add class this `btn-block` for `a`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Class this `btn-block`

```
<li class="nav-item mx-0">
    <a class="nav-link btn-block">foo</a>
</li>
```

or

add this css

```
.nav-item a{
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, making it a block in your css worked a charm. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

this should work with bootstrap 4

```
<li class="nav-item mx-0">
    <a class="nav-link px-0">foo</a>
</li>
```

but if you want to do it manually

```
 .nav-item{
margin-left:0;
margin-right:0;
}

.nav-item a{
padding-left:0;
padding-right:0;
}
```

Comment: Tried both these, but still the same just the text is clickable. Wonder if I have other stuff wrong that is breaking it...

Comment: can you create a fiddle?